# Post controller with File & Body

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm using Nest framework and trying to make a Post request that gets a file and data here's what I did

```
  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFile(@Body('data') addRefundDto:AddRefundDto,@UploadedFile() file) {
    console.log(addRefundDto);
    console.log(addRefundDto.price);
    console.log(addRefundDto.refundType);
    return '   ';
  }
```

which prints :

> {
>        "refundType":"test",
>        "currency":"usd",
>       "price":58.5,
>       "flightId":4,
>       "iAiCard":true
>   }
>
> undefined
>
> undefined

It's like the dto gets the json as text (I also tried calling @Body()instead of @Body('data'))

I removed "Content-Type","application/json" from the request in PostMan so I can upload the file, is there anyway to solve this nicely ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always `JSON.parse(addRefundDto)` to put it back in JSON format. the `body-parser` package will only parse the data if you send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`, otherwise you'll need to parse it yourself (in this case simply with `JSON.parse()`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for someone the solution below will work.

You can use DTO without nested objects.

```
export class SomeDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    public readonly field1: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    public readonly field2: string;

    @ApiProperty({
        format: 'binary',
        type: 'string'
    })
    public readonly file: IMulterFile;
}
```